# Как без цикла поменять значения в заданном массиве на другие?

Tags: python, оптимизация, numpy

Имеется массив:

```
a = np.array([1, 6, 4, 5, 15])
```

Я генерирую рандомно несколько индексов и сохраняю их в список:

```
ind = np.random.choice(len(a), size = len(a), replace=True)
```

Пусть, например, `ind = [0, 3, 1, 0, 1]`.

Теперь, мне нужен другой массив `b`, в котором значения будут соответствовать элементам исходного массива, но под индексами из массива `ind`.  Т.е., в нашем случае массив `b` после преобразований = `1, 5, 6, 1, 6`.

Как мою реализацию заменить на код **без цикла**?

```
for i, j in enumerate(ind):
b = np.zeros_like(a)
    b[i] = a[j]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

просто выберите элементы из вектора `a` по индексу `ind`:

```
res = a[ind]
```

результат:

```
In [16]: res
Out[16]: array([1, 5, 6, 1, 6])
```